# Spring oauth2 client credential grant with WSO2 Identity server

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have couple of spring boot applications which constitute a micro service architecture and need to use WSO2 IS(which is hosted on CLOUD) authentication for authenticating the services(service to service authentication).

I could not find any sample program with **Spring oauth2 client crdential grant with WSO2 Identity server** combination yet.

Any direction would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below. It guides you to achieve your requirement step-by-step.

https://medium.com/@balaajanthan/oauth2-login-for-spring-boot-application-with-wso2-identity-server-da0a88893987